# rsync + renaming the copied files

Tags: rsync, rename, file-copy

Is it possible to change the name of the destination file (add some timestamp as a prefix) when copy is done by `rsync` ?

For example, I can use the following command to change the name of the destination file using suffix:

```
rsync --append  -arzvv --backup --suffix='_2015_09_10' /path/to/src/file /path/to/dst
```

But I would like to attach the time stamp as a prefix, so in the destination we will have some thing like: `2015_09_10_file` instead of `file_2015_09_10`.

Comment: Doubt it -- how would rsync know which files it had copied?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: Your `--suffix` is applied to the backup copy of an existing file, not to the new file, which cannot be renamed. You will have to do the rename after the rsync with a separate command. An alternative is to use a destination directory which is the date, so the file keeps the same name.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you can, but kind of hacky.. and only as suffix.

As you have read in the comments, `--suffix` is for backups of overwritten files. So you rsync the same files from source to destination, kind of forcing rsync to overwrite (`-I`) - but only if the source file is (`-u`) newer (which it never is) and using the `-b, --backup` option and define a backup directory and a suffix.

`rsync -Iu --backup --suffix='_2015_09_10' --backup-dir=/path/to/dst /path/to/src/file /path/to/src/file`

Answer (score 2):

Rsync cannot do this at the level of individual files, but has some support for doing whole trees. E.g.:

```
/path/to/dst-2019-07-31/file
/path/to/dst-2019-07-30/file
/path/to/dst-2019-07-29/file
...
```

There are three options:

- `--compare-dest=DIR` where only new files are created in the new directory. This is probably not what you want because you'd have to list *all* the previous version directories.
- `--copy-dest=DIR` where unchanged files are copied from `DIR` to the destination rather than transferring them from the source.
- `--link-dest=DIR` is the same, but uses much less disk space on the destination because it does not duplicate the file contents.

You use it like this:

```
rsync -a --link-dest=/path/to/dst-$YESTERDAY /path/to/src /path/to/dst-$TODAY
```

Answer (score 0):

It is straightforward to rename individual files rsync transfers:

```bsh
rsync /path/to/original_name.txt /path/new/my_new_file_name.txt
```

Just specify the filename in the destination path, and that becomes the new filename. In OP's case, this doesn't help because they want to use *part* of the existing filename to rename the a whole bunch of files. But I'm adding this to make the Q/A more generally helpful.